# Get the value of an element in an array when is used addEventListener click?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Well, I have several projects with title and description in a html code. Every title has a class "nameProject" and I use the following code to get all of them:

```
var projects = document.querySelectorAll(".nameProject");
```

And the problem begins here... I'd want that when a user click on one of those titles I can get the value of that specific title. And I'm using this code:

```
for (var i=0; i<projects.length; i++){
projects[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
alert("Your title is: " + projects[i].value);
});
}
```

But when I use this code in Javascript, it doesn´t work!! I don't understand what I'm doing wrong :( could you please give me a hand?
BTW: Sorry for my english, I'm not native

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `var` creates a variable in the context of a function (or global context in this case), it's value is that of the latest `i` (the length of `projects`).

To solve that problem you can use `let`, which is scoped to the block (the curly brackets), and the value of each instance of `i` is preserved in the block.

See this question - [What's the difference between using “let” and “var”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/762011/5157454)

```js
var projects = document.querySelectorAll(".nameProject");

for (let i = 0; i < projects.length; i++) {
  projects[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    alert("Your title is: " + projects[i].value);
  });
}
```

```html
<button class="nameProject" value="A">Button 1</button><button class="nameProject" value="B">Button 2</button><button class="nameProject" value="C">Button 3</button><button class="nameProject" value="D">Button 4</button><button class="nameProject" value="E">Button 5</button>
```

Another option is to use [`NodeList.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach), and skip the need to use indexes:

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".nameProject")
  .forEach(el => {
    el.addEventListener('click', function() {
      alert("Your title is: " + el.value);
    });
  });
```

```html
<button class="nameProject" value="A">Button 1</button><button class="nameProject" value="B">Button 2</button><button class="nameProject" value="C">Button 3</button><button class="nameProject" value="D">Button 4</button><button class="nameProject" value="E">Button 5</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest rather than setting up a different event listener, setting up a global one that works across all of them. Also, because you mentioned you are listening for clicks on titles and not fields/buttons, I will be using `textContent` instead of `value` in my example below, but please correct me if I am mistaken.

```js
document.addEventListener('click', e => e.target?.matches('.nameProject') && alert(e.target.textContent));
```

```html
<h2 class="nameProject">Title 1</h2>
<h2 class="nameProject">Title 2</h2>
<h2 class="nameProject">Title 3</h2>
<h2 class="nameProject">Title 4</h2>
<h2 class="nameProject">Title 5</h2>
```